# Docker. Postgres. pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

##### Trying to connect to postgresDB from pgAdmin4. Both are conteinerised via docker compose and are in same network `backend-db-prod`

### launching script

```bash
docker compose --env-file ./.docker/.db.env --env-file ./.docker/.pgadmin.env -f ./.docker/compose.db.yaml up --build --wait
```

### `compose.db-env.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  postgres-pg-admin-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

### `compose.db.yaml`

```
version: "3.8"

include:
  - ./compose.db-env.yaml

services:
  db-prod:
    container_name: backend-db-prod
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 4G
    env_file: ./.db.env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-db}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT:-5432}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    image: postgres:16.1-alpine3.18
    networks:
      - postgres-pg-admin-net
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./.postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql.conf

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 1G
    depends_on:
      - db-prod
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7.4
    env_file: ./.pgadmin.env
    environment:
      MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED: ${MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED:-False}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: ${PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE:-False}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.com}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - ./.pgadmin.servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - postgres-pg-admin-net
```

### `.db.env`

```
POSTGRES_CONTAINER_NAME=backend-db-dev
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
```

### `.pgadmin.dev`

```
MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED=False
PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=False
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
```

#### `.pgadmin.servers.json` - file to pre-configure servers list at pgAdmin4, im using net-name alias provided by docker to set `Host`

```json
{
  "Servers": {
    "main": {
      "Name": "main",
      "Group": "Servers",
      "Port": 5432,
      "Username": "postgres",
      "Host": "backend-db-dev",
      "SSLMode": "prefer",
      "MaintenanceDB": "postgres"
    }
  }
}
```

when containers are built Im trying to connect from pgAdmin4 to postgres's DB and getting this
[image]

this is database connection settings:

[image]

here you can see what alias the container has in the docker network:

[image]

## Question:

How to establish connection properly? What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using "backend-db-dev" in pgadmin while the container is named backend-db-prod. The connection doesn't not work because these 2 do not match.